# How to not get blocked while scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape Transfermarkt, a football web. I'm trying to do web scraping but every time y try I get blocked at 7th request.

I have try to change headers and proxies but I always get the same result.

These are some "experiments" I did. These proxies works separated.

```
user_agent_list = [here are a lot of user agents]
headers = {'User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list)}
url='https://www.transfermarkt.es/jadon-sancho/profil/spieler/14'

r=requests.get(url,headers='User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list),proxies={'http': 'http://121.121.117.227:3128'})
print(r)
r=requests.get(url,headers='User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list),proxies={'http': 'http://121.121.117.227:3128'})
print(r)
r=requests.get(url,headers='User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list),proxies={'http': 'http://121.121.117.227:3128'})
print(r)

#Changing proxy
r=requests.get(url,headers='User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list),proxies={'http': 'http://177.131.22.186:80'})
print(r)
r=requests.get(url,headers='User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list),proxies={'http': 'http://177.131.22.186:80'})
print(r)
r=requests.get(url,headers='User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list),proxies={'http': 'http://177.131.22.186:80'})
print(r)
#Here I get blocked
r=requests.get(url,headers='User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list),proxies={'http': 'http://177.131.22.186:80'})
print(r)
#And continue trying with another examples
```

I have to remark that proxies are validated, so then work individually. What I get from prints are  until I get blocked that I get . How should I solve it? Should I change another parameter from the get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem with your script is that you are trying to connect to `https` server with `http only` proxy. You need to set a proxy for `https`:

```
proxies={'https': 'https://x.y.z.a:b'}
```

In your case you are only setting `http` proxy, so `https` requests are not going through it.

> Please note that proxy servers you have given in your example don't
>   support `https`.

Comment: I have tried 'https' and both of then at the same dictionary and I get the requests.exceptions.ConnectionError(). And using http I get at least 6 requests.

Comment: Told you that proxies that you are using **ARE NOT SUPPORTING** `https`, you need to get `https` proxy server list. When you are using `http` setting for `https` server, your connection runs directly (it doesn't use `http` proxy server at all).

Comment: As far as I know I'm doing that:   r=requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent':random.choice(user_agent_list)},proxies={'https': 'https://202.49.183.168:46110'})
That proxy was gotten from a https list.

Comment: That proxy is dead.

Comment: Try this one: 23.20.214.120:3128